# Directory Created but File not saveing inside the folder

Tags: c#, asp.net

In here userwise create a folder and i wanted to save file inside the user folder.
Im success until create the folder but after that when im going to save the file,it's unsuccessful.

Error Shows

> The SaveAs method is configured to require a rooted path

My Code

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (string s in Request.Files)
    {
        HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[s];
        int fileSizeInBytes = file.ContentLength;
        string fileName = file.FileName;
        string fileExtension = "";

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
            fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
            Guid UserGUID = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;

            string UserFolderPath = "~/UploadedFiles/" + UserGUID;
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(UserFolderPath));

        //Upto this line it's OK.Below this,Not save the files inside the directory
       //I have no idea below 2 lines are correct or not

            string savedFileName = Path.Combine(UserFolderPath);
            file.SaveAs(UserFolderPath);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine the folder with the file's name to obtain the final path to send to `SaveAs`:

```
string savedFileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(UserFolderPath), fileName);
file.SaveAs(savedFileName);
```